# No members available when using typedef

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, intellisense, typedef

Let's assume I have a class `A`, which has public method called `init()`. When I create `std::vector` of objects of type `A`, I can easily call this method for all objects:

```
std::vector<A> v;

/* filling vector with some objects */

v[1].init();   // Intellisense finds that v[1] object has method 'init()'
```

But when I use typedef, I cannot access that method:

```
typedef std::vector<A> a_vector;

a_vector v;

/* filling vector with some objects */

v[1].   // Intellisense says that v[1] object doesn't have any members available
```

Why use of `typedef` is causing such behaviour?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: @Aesthete Visual Studio 2012

Comment: The problem is just with Intellisense; the code will still compile just fine. It's a fact of life that Intellisense gets confused easily.

Comment: Second case (typedef) works correct for me. I used VS2008. Do you use namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably just a glitch in VS2012's cache symbol definitions file. Close your solution, delete the sdf file found in your solution directory (named [SolutionName].sdf) and re-open your solution. Give the symbols cache a few minutes to re-build (depends on the size of your project) and hope for the best. Rinse and repeat whenever something goes wrong (and it will, especially for solutions that include large quantities of code).